# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) and KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xbf83458c

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-leaks, bluetooth, automatic-ref-counting

I am getting weird crash in my application running in iOS 7 but in iOS 6 app is working fine. I am performing some operations. After 5-6 operations are completed I am experiencing this crash. This number can go till 20 also or 1 also. Attaching crash log with this. All the experts please help.

```
Incident Identifier: BBF3B8D2-D354-41CA-83DA-A94FF3558B9B
CrashReporter Key:   6c98458a7e4d9788a107c8ae73ffba9a155bb338
Hardware Model:      iPod5,1
Process:             mobile [1191]
Path:                ---
Identifier:          ---
Version:             2.0.0.401
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-05-30 18:48:14.506 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xbf83458c
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3829e626 objc_msgSend + 6
1   UIKit                           0x30400fce -[UINavigationItem leftBarButtonItems] + 30
2   UIKit                           0x303f99fa -[UINavigationBar tintColorDidChange] + 130
3   UIKit                           0x306e33c4 -[_UITintColorVisitor _visitView:] + 432
4   UIKit                           0x306e3abc _UIViewVisitorEntertainVisitors + 84
5   UIKit                           0x306e2d88 _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors + 124
6   UIKit                           0x306e2e14 _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors + 264
7   UIKit                           0x306e2e14 _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors + 264
8   UIKit                           0x306e2e14 _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors + 264
9   UIKit                           0x306e2bc6 +[_UIViewVisitor _startTraversalOfVisitor:withView:] + 322
10  UIKit                           0x305fab40 -[UIView _dispatchTintColorVisitorWithReasons:] + 128
11  UIKit                           0x3057cf5a -[_UIModalItemsPresentingViewController _resaturateUI] + 246
12  UIKit                           0x305766da -[_UIModalItemsPresentingViewController _dismissItem:andPresentItem:animated:completion:keepDimmingView:] + 3014
13  UIKit                           0x30575b0a -[_UIModalItemsPresentingViewController _dismissItem:andPresentItem:animated:completion:] + 34
14  UIKit                           0x3057cddc -[_UIModalItemsCoordinator _dismissItem:withTappedButtonIndex:animated:notifyDelegate:] + 680
15  UIKit                           0x3073f70c -[UIViewController(UIModalItemPresentationSupport) dismissModalItem:withTappedButtonIndex:animated:] + 96
16  UIKit                           0x308039a0 -[UIAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:] + 128
17  mobile                  0x000b30b4 -[MainViewController hideCurrentAlert] (MainViewController.m:785)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x2db0c1ee __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 10
19  CoreFoundation                  0x2da8053a _CFXNotificationPost + 1714
20  Foundation                      0x2e46aa38 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
21  Foundation                      0x2e46f316 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 26
22  mobile                  0x001ec600 -[VFIPWLm postNotification:] (VFIPWLm.m:105)
23  mobile                  0x0020d354 -[VFIPWLm startTransaction:origAmount:finalAmount:surcharge:invoice:discount:promocode:chequeData:AVSAddress:AVSPostcode:email:refTransactionID:gpsLatitude:gpsLongitude:merchID:terminalID:allowRefundSystemByID:status:statusMsg:tranID:authCode:totalCharge:signatureRequired:voiceAuthPhone:merchantID:tipAmount:receiptData:cardScheme:] (VFIPWLm.m:3001)
24  mobile                  0x000b8060 -[MainViewController startTran] (MainViewController.m:1868)
25  mobile                  0x000bfaac -[MainViewController showView] (MainViewController.m:3283)
26  Foundation                      0x2e533b00 __NSFireTimer + 60
27  CoreFoundation                  0x2db151b4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
28  CoreFoundation                  0x2db14dca __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 778
29  CoreFoundation                  0x2db13166 __CFRunLoopRun + 1206
30  CoreFoundation                  0x2da7df0a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
31  CoreFoundation                  0x2da7dcee CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
32  GraphicsServices                0x3299f65e GSEventRunModal + 134
33  UIKit                           0x303c9168 UIApplicationMain + 1132
34  mobile                  0x000b01e6 main (main.m:15)
35  libdyld.dylib                   0x387a1ab4 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38844808 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x38786078 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x38785dfe _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 34

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38844a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38844854 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2db14896 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2db12fbc __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2da7df0a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2da7dcee CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   WebCore                         0x35d5e116 RunWebThread(void*) + 414
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388c0916 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388c0886 _pthread_start + 98
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388beaa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38857434 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2db18758 __CFSocketManager + 480
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388c0916 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388c0886 _pthread_start + 98
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388beaa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  GCDAsyncSocket-CFStream
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38844a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38844854 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2db14896 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2db12fbc __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2da7df0a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2da7dcee CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x2e4701e6 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   Foundation                      0x2e4c109c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
8   paywaremobile                   0x00138a38 +[GCDAsyncSocket cfstreamThread] (GCDAsyncSocket.m:6741)
9   Foundation                      0x2e532a5a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388c0916 _pthread_body + 138
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388c0886 _pthread_start + 98
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388beaa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38844a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38844854 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2db14896 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2db12fbc __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2da7df0a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2da7dcee CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x2e4bd082 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 314
7   Foundation                      0x2e532a5a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388c0916 _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388c0886 _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388beaa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38844a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38844854 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2db14896 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2db12fbc __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2da7df0a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2dac19fe CFRunLoopRun + 94
6   CoreMotion                      0x2e13b3a8 ___lldb_unnamed_function1423$$CoreMotion + 724
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388c0916 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388c0886 _pthread_start + 98
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388beaa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38857c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388bebda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388bea94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38857c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388bebda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388bea94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38857c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388bebda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388bea94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x388481a8 kevent + 24
1   ExternalAccessory               0x2e45b67a -[EAInputStream _readInputFromAccThread] + 382
2   Foundation                      0x2e532a5a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388c0916 _pthread_body + 138
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388c0886 _pthread_start + 98
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x388beaa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x16551700    r1: 0x3099227d      r2: 0x38ecf908      r3: 0x0000002c
    r4: 0x1657b2f0    r5: 0x27d6ba84      r6: 0x16508cd0      r7: 0x27d6b9c8
    r8: 0x27d6bb28    r9: 0xbf834580     r10: 0x27d6bcb8     r11: 0x309e6528
    ip: 0x38de332c    sp: 0x27d6b9c8      lr: 0x30400fd3      pc: 0x3829e626
```

Comment: Sometimes turning on zombies (http://stackoverflow.com/q/5386160/1271826) can help identify situations where you are trying to access a deallocated object (which is a common source of this sort of problem).

Comment: Apparently, the problem is located (thread 0) around -[MainViewController hideCurrentAlert] (line 785). Look for a deallocated object. Are you using ARC? A glance at your code could be helpful to help you.

Comment: No I am not using ARC. Problem is every time crash report is different. Just now got another report.